# Need to convert to magento MVC structure

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

I have developed a code that contains a aquery which returns ratings of a product in json format. The code is as follows:

```
<?php header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
require_once('/opt/phpapps/magento/app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();
$cid=$_GET['catid'];
$read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$query = "SELECT round(t1.rating_summary / 20) AS rating, t2.product_id FROM review_entity_summary AS t1 INNER JOIN catalog_category_product AS t2 ON t1.entity_pk_value = t2.product_id WHERE category_id =" . $cid . " AND store_id = '1'";

$results = $read->fetchAll($query);
$json = json_encode($results);
print_r( $json );
?>
```

I am instructed to convert this into MVC pattern. I knew that MVC can be done by creating separate folders like blocks, controllers, models,sql,etc, helpers folders. But I am not sure what is the next stepa nd how to execute the developed to get the json data..
Help me in this...

Comment: You should create your own module (see link from Andrew) and use one Controller to generate your json. Now you can call it with AJAX or whatever you need).

Comment: You've got a long way to go, probably more than what you will get answered here.

Comment: @benmarks i think u got my problem. Can u say how can I reach my target?? I came to know that by extending a controller in app/code/core/Mage/Rating/Model/rating.php we can solve my issue. If this is right or wrong I need ur suggestion upon this... And also How can i get rid of this...

Comment: I've got a JSON order export tool. It's easiest as a standalone file. The only thing MVC would be for is so you can "install" it and/or control it in the admin back end. :P imho, bad request made upon you. Thankfully, making module isn't impossible. I did my 1st this week

Answer (score 1):

The best way to is create a custom Extension/Model, there's a lot of tutorials out there to do this, however you could use something to generate an example for you to get started:

http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

However, for something this simple you could just create a custom block in the local namespace, for example:

app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Ratingsjson.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Ratingsjson.php
 */
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Ratingsjson extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Get products with special offer attribute set
     * 
     * @return type
     */
    public function getRatings() 
    { 
        /**
         * This will be injected from the tag / XML below
         * you can pass what ever variables you want this way.
         * getSomeAttribute() will get the value 'some_attribute' from the
         * CMS tag or XML config.
         */
        $categoryId = $this->getCategoryId();
        if($categoryId == NULL) {
             $categoryId = 1; // or some default;
        }

        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $read = $resource->getConnection('catalog_read');

        // Do your stuff here...
        $query = "SELECT round(t1.rating_summary / 20) AS rating, t2.product_id FROM review_entity_summary AS t1 INNER JOIN catalog_category_product AS t2 ON t1.entity_pk_value = t2.product_id WHERE category_id =" . $cid . " AND store_id = '1'";
        $results = $read->fetchAll($query);

        return json_encode($results);
    }
}
```

Create a template to do what you want:

template/mymodeule/mytemplate.phtml

```
<?php
echo $this->getRatings();
```

You can then use your new block inside CMS pages:

```
{{block type="catalog/ratignsjson" category_id="3" temaplte="mymodeule/mytemplate.phtml"}}
```

Or if you want to load it via XML config:

```
<block type="catalog/ratignsjson" category_id="3" name="ratignsjson" template="mymodeule/mytemplate.phtml"/>
```

To do this properly and output strict Json data you would want to set json content type headers etc but I think that's a little too much for this particular case.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply..Bt from which page I will give the input, like the category ID to the code?

Comment: Just added an example of how you can specify the category you need to use.

Comment: thank u for giving me the brief explination about this.. I dont want to do this with template. I wants to return the data in json format when we are going to run the controller. If I run this controller trough the URl, it shows 404 error I knew it because XMl page wasnt created. So is this problem is due to not of creation of XML file???

Comment: That code is for displaying the output of your custom Block inside a CMS page or another page, not directly from the controller.
If you use the module creator you will see an example of how to make a mocule with a controller, from which you can display json code if you wish